# Microservice request has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: microservices, network

We see the following error in the browser console when making a simple ajax request to monitor the health of the Discovery service:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://host:port/health' from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Here is the simple request we're making:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var serviceURL = "http://host:port/health";
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: serviceURL,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  "crossDomain": true,
  responseType:'application/json',
  success: function(data ) {
    console.log(data.status);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("FAIL");
  }
});
```

});

The SDL documentation states that CORS is disabled:
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-0AED86F8-FDA0-4543-A2A3-D866396D8E51

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? For example, is there any way to enable CORS for a specific domain/port?

Comment: Why do you want to access the health check endpoint from a browser using a CORS request? These health check endpoints are intended for load balancers.

Comment: We're creating a page to monitor the health of all our microservices